# Fastboot commands hangs

Tags: fastboot, lg, lg-g2

I have an LG G2 and Windows 7 operating system, I've been having this problem on Linux too. Basically Any command I issue to the phone with fastboot gets stuck at some point. If I try to flash recovery fastboot hangs at `writing 'recovery'`

`fastboot devices` returns a question mark.

I have usb driver installed, Adb sees phone during normal operation (I'm on on Windows-7), fastboot doesn't see it when in fastboot mode. If I try to use Android SDK latest usb drivers Windows 7 says it has already the latest drivers for my phone.

This is what happens when I send `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img`

```
target reported max download size of 1862270976 bytes     
sending 'recovery' (11056 KB)... OKAY [ 0.406s]     
writing 'recovery'...
```

And then the process hangs there. There was a time when doing the same operation yielded the error message "too many links" or something similar I cannot remember exactly or reproduce it again.

Comment: Adb sees phone during normal operation, fastboot doesn't see it when in fastboot mode. I read on another question that the device while in fastboot mode has a different id than when operating normally. I'm going to reinstall the drivers and see what happens.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?